# Promo codes à-la Deliveroo

Tags: ios, promotion-code

Our app was rejected because it allowed users to enter promo codes to get a discounted version of our subscriptions. Both the original and the discounted products were published through the iTunes Store and paid through the IAP but we were told that the app contravened [section 3.1.1](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) of their guidelines.

Now we are stuck and we wonder how apps like Deliveroo work: does anybody have a clue on how such functionality can be implemented and approved through the Apple review process?

Comment: I don't understand how deliveroo is relevant to your situation; they provide real-world services so they don't (and cannot) use IAP

Comment: Right, from your answer I understand that we are not allowed to use promo codes because we are using IAP, which is something we suspected although we were not sure about, thanks

Comment: You can offer [Introductory Pricing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in_app_purchase/offering_introductory_pricing_in_your_app) or free trial periods but they cannot be linked to promo codes; they must be available to all users.